# border-right not showing on first li

Tags: jquery, css

I have a specific issue with the following example:
http://jsfiddle.net/c7NyZ/8/

Open it in IE7 or do IE7 mode. The first LI (border-right) seems to have merged with the 2nd li.

I am using a jquery library for the rounded corners.

Can you help me show the border right again like the others?

Comment: _"I have a specific issue with the following example"_ sounds too localized to me...

Comment: English isnt my strong point. I have an issue with the merged li. This is due to the rounded corners. If you take the JS out it shows up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem has to do with the rounded corners that are not soported in IE<9
you can run this -

```
$("ul#top-nav li:first").corner("tl: 5px bl:5px ");
$("ul#top-nav li:last").corner("tr: 5px br:5px ");​
```

if not IE<9
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/